# Unable to get start time and end time of embedded videos from IFrame

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp, jstl

We are doing a learning web application where we have to show list of videos to user , these videos can be uploaded as embedded URL so when user play the same embedded URL then we are unable to store the values of start , pause and end time of the video, We are using iFrame tag for show videos

Tried to capture the values from iFrame but haven't reach the goal.
searched a lot on net but couldn't get satisfy able content.

```
<iframe width="670" height="400" id="vid${v.video_id}" src="${v.embedded_url}"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one.. , just replace "url" from following code to your src url

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="url ?start=1" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```